# Far-field in air versus vacuum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, approximations, antennas

I think the far-field is significantly different in vacuum versus air, is this true? More specifically, when we talk about far-field, we mean the electromagnetic wave as a whole etc. but in the near field we can have the magnetic component in one way or ways and the electric in another. For example one direction could be almost entirely magnetic with almost no electric field to it. Only when this interacts with electrons will it start to convert from one to the other, eventually having equal parts in electric and magnetic, so then we call it far-field. But what if there are never any electrons to encounter, I think that would extend the far-field, perhaps to infinity. Does this sound correct?

[image]

Comment: No.  The electrons are in the wire, not in the air.  Once it radiates, they are photons, not electrons.  The only difference air makes is that it might attenuate the signal by absorbing some frequencies slightly.  Ground makes a bigger difference.

Comment: I think you are wrong. If the antenna itself was in space and maybe it was an array.

Comment: @Jack0220 your comment makes no sense. Both in air as in vacuum, there's no "free" electrons (or any charge carriers) with which your wave interacts.

Comment: The hypothesis of the question ignores basic discoveries by Faraday and Maxwell about E & M & EM fields.

Comment: Whoa, let's not insult your question.  You're just trying to understand and learn, and that's commendable.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to learn and understand. I insulated my own question because it was getting so many down-votes, yet at least to me it is an interesting question.

Comment: Some people down-vote posts that betray an incorrect understanding of theory.  Of course when you're learning, incorrect understanding comes with the territory: it helps bridge the gap temporarily between ignorance and true understanding.  In other words, when you're trying to learn, sometimes you just have to ignore the downvotes.

Comment: I know there have been answers here @Jack0220, but I think this will be received more favorably on Physics.  Would you object to me migrating it there?

Comment: You can migrate it, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the far-field is significantly different in vacuum versus air, is this true?

No, exactly the same equations (Maxwell!) apply; only the $\varepsilon_r$ and $\mu_r$ are different – but to a very minor degree. Hard to measure even with lab equipment.

> More specifically, when we talk about far-field, we mean the electromagnetic wave as a whole etc.

Hm, not really, no. "Far-field" describes the location.
When I say "far-field wavefront", I describe the wavefront in all places that I consider far field.

> but in the near field we can have the magnetic component in one way or ways and the electric in another.

That's always the case: E- and H-field are orthogonal in isotropic media.

> For example one direction could be almost entirely magnetic with almost no electric field to it.

As said, practically always the case, unless your medium is "special".

> Only when this interacts with electrons will it start to convert from one to the other, eventually having equal parts in electric and magnetic, so then we call it far-field.

No, none of this is correct.

> But what if there are never any electrons to encounter, I think that would extend the far-field, perhaps to infinity. Does this sound correct?

No.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130451/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-far-field-in-air-versus-vacuum).

Answer (score 3):

> Only when this interacts with electrons will it start to convert from one to the other

No! The EM field interacts with *itself*; it doesn't need any help from electrons. Maxwell's equations give the differential equations that govern this, and show that the wave propagates at the speed of light.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the magnetic field is expanding from the source into infinity, same for the electric field. I see no reason why the 2 necessarily have to exist together. How would a spinning magnet in space create an electric field (of the same magnitude no less), it just comes out of nowhere or what? Tell me how and I might believe you.

Comment: @Jack0220 -- the term "electromagnetic field" refers to a **combination** of electric and magnetic fields. Each field reinforces the other, and its the combination of the two that makes up the wave.

Comment: @PeteNU9W each reinforces the other, I would agree with you in the presence of electrons but not out in space. What I think is, we always see them together so we assume they come from each other but did anyone ever pause to think that maybe both fields are just always created together but that it doesn't have to be that way. A magnetic field wiggling an electron also creates an electric and vice versa, but without electron I don't see how.

Comment: @Jack0220 -- no, each reinforces the other directly, without the need for electrons. You keep rejecting references to the mathematics that describe it, but without the math your intuition will lead you astray. That's the problem that 19th century physicists ran into, which led them to invent the "aether", which was the substance that light waves supposedly vibrated in. Experiments proved that there was no aether. To repeat the previous mantra: Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Not at least knowing the math is certainly a shortcoming, it would help. So let me ask you this @PeteNU9W, a balloon charged up by hair produces an electric field AND a magnetic field? a magnet laying on my desk produces a magnetic field AND an electric field? I always thought those were 2 separate things.

Comment: @Jack0220 -- there are standalone electric fields, and there are standalone magnetic fields, just as you've described. And, yes, those are two separate things. If you **vibrate** that balloon its electric charge combined with the motion produces a changing magnetic field, and that, in turn, produces a changing electric field. The two reinforce each other as they move in tandem away from the balloon, and that's an electromagnetic wave.

Comment: @PeteNU9W i think we are getting somewhere. so the new understanding should for me should be: we have electric and magnetic fields separate from each other when the electrons (ex balloon) are not changing (aka. bobbing up and down), but as soon as the bobbing starts, now all of a sudden the 2 fields no longer exist separately but are now one thing. So at 0.000000000 Hz separate fields, and at 0.000000001 Hz they are together, am I getting this correctly?